# Как удалить весь текст до точки Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
text = "Маши́на  — техническое приспособление выполняющее механические движения для преобразования энергии, материалов и информации.В более расширенном современном определении, появившемся с развитием электроники, машиной является технический объект, состоящий из взаимосвязанных функциональных частей , использующий энергию для выполнения возложенных на него функций. В этом понимании машина может и не содержать механически движущихся частей. Примером таких устройств служат электронно-вычислительная машина , электрический трансформатор, ускоритель заряженных частиц."
print(текст после первой точки)
```

Как вывести весь текст после первой точки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [str.partition(sep)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
print(text.partition('.')[2])
```

результат:

```
В более расширенном современном определении, появившемся с развитием электроники, машиной является технический объект, состоящий из взаимосвязанных функциональных частей , использующий энергию для выполнения возложенных на него функций. В этом понимании машина может и не содержать механически движущихся частей. Примером таких устройств служат электронно-вычислительная машина , электрический трансформатор, ускоритель заряженных частиц.
```

---

более наглядный пример:

```
In [43]: "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9".partition(".")
Out[43]: ('1', '.', '2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9')
```